How to retain screen animation option when using useNavigationBuilder in react navigation
I am building a custom tab navigation with the useNavigationBuilder, the content part of the screen is rendered using {descriptors[route.key].render()}. This however does not respect the animation set in screen options for each route. Can this be achieved? setting the animation on the view does not look great as on the first render its not reflecting either.
I want the slide-in animation when moving from orders to order details. Screen option for order-details is defined as
   {
      name: 'order-details',
      component: Order,
      options: {
        headerLeft: WithPreviousRouteComponent,
        headerTitle: '',
        headerTransparent: true,
        headerStyle: false,
        headerShown: true,
        animation: 'slide_from_right',
        animationDuration: ANIMATION_DURATION,
      },
    },




Can you provide a more complete example?
Is the animation you mean for the Stack or the Tab ?

hi @MichaelBahl, the animation is for the stack (i am using the native stack here). i.e what is shown in the content view (orders in the screenshot)
